# How can I change the style of the split bar in a JSplitPane?

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I am using `JSplitPane`s for some of my panels, but they are a bit thick, especially when you have a few of them showing.

Is it possible to style these bars into something thinner, like a line with an arrow, or even just a line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setDividerSize` to it in order to change its width. Its default value is 10. Full example:

```
public class SplitPaneTest extends JFrame {
    public SplitPaneTest() {
        super("test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        JPanel right = new JPanel();

        JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, left, right);
        System.out.println(sp.getDividerSize()); //Prints 10
        sp.setDividerSize(1);

        add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new SplitPaneTest().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

However, [Look & Feels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) are capable of changing the way it looks since they change its `UI`. If the above solution does not work for you, you will have to mess with its UI. For example, in one of my applications I did not want any line (while using Windows Look and Feel), so in order to make it invisible I had to:

```
sp.setUI(new BasicSplitPaneUI() {
    @Override
    public BasicSplitPaneDivider createDefaultDivider() {
        return new BasicSplitPaneDivider(this) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -6000773723083732304L;

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                //Divider gets no painting
            }
        };
    }
});
```